# Please Help..Dual Boot Question

Tags: dual-boot

This is probably simple to explain/resolve but I need help with dual booting.

I have win7 installed. I just installed Ubuntu. Before the Ubuntu installation, I took the necessary steps. Such as create new partition, assign for storage space and also swap space. Once, I started installation everything went smoothly. However, after confirming "no" to import settings from win7 to Ubuntu (such as mozilla firefox settings etc. for users) I restarted the computer to complete the install.

Naturally, in a dual boot situation the PC displays which system to start (win7 or Ubuntu). **I don't get this screen. It just boots directly to Ubuntu.** *I need to be able to choose either win7 or Ubuntu.*

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

I know my win7 loader is in dev/sda1 and I think that I also updated the grub...PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set timer in grub so when it loads you can choose which OS to boot. To do so follow this steps

1. Open Terminal
2. In the terminal enter `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Locate the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and set the value 10 for example. So it will look like this `GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"`
4. In order to see the grub menu you have to comment the following line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`. To comment a line you should add # at the begging. So it will look like this `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`
5. Save the file and close it.
6. Then update the grub config by executing command `sudo update-grub`
   Now you should be able to see boot menu where is your Ubuntu and Windows listed.

In order to reinstall grub we are going to use tool called **Boot-repair**  Actual quote from Ubuntu community wiki

> Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

To repair GRUB follow these steps:

1. boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
2. choose "Try Ubuntu"
3. connect internet
4. open a new Terminal, then type:

   **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update**
5. Press Enter.
6. Then type:

   **sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair**
7. Press Enter

Using Boot-Repair

Recommended repair

1. launch Boot-Repair from either : the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the
   top-left of the screen) or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
2. Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished,
   note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then
   reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

Hope this help to restore access to your systems.

Comment: Nikki Kononov, I tried the things that you said. It still does not work. Here is what it looks like: # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Comment: Is there any other options? Thank you!

Comment: you forgot to put quotes on GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 they needed! so it must look like GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"

Comment: just put in the quotes...its still not working. I know I did the install correctly because Ubuntu is showing installed on only 68.00GB that I allocated for it...what do you think might be the problem?? I appreciate your help and effort!

Comment: here is what the terminal looks like  edi@edi-GN703AA-ABA-a6228x:~$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
[sudo] password for edi: 
edi@edi-GN703AA-ABA-a6228x:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic-pae
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
edi@edi-GN703AA-ABA-a6228x:~$

Comment: Try to hold Shift button when you load your computer. It should show grub menu.

Comment: I tried to hold shift as you said, I got the black screen and in the UPPER LEFT CORNER---"GRUB LOADING" that shows up for about two seconds and then dissapears, after that PC boots into UBUNTU AGAIN..

Comment: hm then I have no idea why grub don't work to work. Perhaps it was installed incorrectly. You might want to reinstall grub. It is pretty easy and do not require deleting existing OS'es or anything. I will update first post ASAP.

Comment: Thank you Nikki, I re-installed Ubuntu again last night. The same problem persists. I will be looking forward to your post. Also, is there anything that I can show you from my system that might help you determine the best solution? Any screen-shots etc...

Comment: If you can send me a screenshot of the grub config file or a copy of the file itself I might figure out what is wrong. The file I need it located by this path sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6113/discussion-between-user96274-and-nikki-kononov)