# Windows 7 won't boot

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu from my live CD and chose to install it alongside Windows. Yesterday, everything worked just fine and I was able to boot from either OS. However today, only Ubuntu will boot and Windows 7 fails to start every time I attempt to (even after restoring my Windows 7 partition to the last known good date).

What could have changed over night that caused this? I did install all the recommended updates for Ubuntu.  Is my only option going to be to wipe my HDD and reinstall both Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: I suggest you ask Nikki here at the askubuntu forum...here is the link: She helped me solve my issue wit dual booting (PC booted into Ubuntu instead of showing grub menu) http://askubuntu.com/users/52970/nikki-kononov Or you can check out what we went through and try it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/199389/please-help-dual-boot-question

Answer (score 0):

Hello Johnny there might be no need to **format** you HDD there is still some hope for your ***Windows 7 installation*.** Hoping that you have a working DVD ROM. Use your Windows repair disk and this should do the trick! The problem with your installation is that your **boot MGR** might have been corrupted the **Windows repair disk** will most probably do the trick. If you do not posses one ask your friends but most probably you PC Manufacturer gave you one. If all else fails then try this

> **Restoring Windows MBR without a Windows CD**
>
> > If you want to boot directly to Windows but Grub has overwritten the MBR, the normal procdeure is to use the Windows CD to restore things. If you do not have access to the Windows CD, the following commands will rewrite the MBR, removing Grub and allowing the system to boot directly into Windows.
> >
> > > Boot the Ubuntu LiveCD, open a terminal (Applications, Accessories, Terminal) and enter the following commands. Make sure you correctly identify the Windows device (normally sda):

**Code**

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

**Note** **You will lose the option of booting into Ubuntu** so if you do not want to do this I suggest you follow the instructions on this page [How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7 bootloader](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708)

Hope all this works!